# Many drop-down menù with search tool in the same page doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I found a Cs/Js layout for a drop-down menù with a search tool... So I copied and pasted the first button but the search tool in the second one doesn't work.

Here the html / js code:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button onMouseOver="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Drop-down</button>
            <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." id="myInput" onkeyup="filterFunction()">
                <a href="#">Link_1 </a>
                <a href="#">Link_2 </a>
          </div>
          </div>

        <div class="dropdown">
            <button onMouseOver="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Drop-down 2</button>
            <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." id="myInput" onkeyup="filterFunction()">
                <a href="#">Link_3 </a>
                <a href="#">Link_4 </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script>


            function myFunction() {
                document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
            }

            function filterFunction() {
                var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
                input = document.getElementById("myInput");
                filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
                div = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
                a = div.getElementsByTagName("a");

                for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
                if (a[i].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                a[i].style.display = "";
                } else {
                    a[i].style.display = "none";
                }
            }
        }

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now I put Css code:

```
#myInput {
    border-box: box-sizing;
    background-image: url('../Website/Img/searchicon.png');
    background-position: 14px 12px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 14px 20px 12px 45px;
    border: none;
    width: 100%;
}

.dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 10%;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 2;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    font-size: 18px;
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #eee}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
   display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}
```

Sorry if there's too much code but I have no idea why it doesn' work!! The problem is that in the 2nd button the search tool doesn'work! Help me please :'(

Comment: I'm very glad to help, @FilippoScaramuzza!  Mind selecting mine as the correct answer, if it's solved your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the same id for both dropdown elements and search inputs this doesn't work ids are unique so it triggers only the first time. I duplicated your js for separate ids and it works. There are better ways to do that just want to show you your mistake ^^

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown2").classList.toggle("show");
}

function filterFunction() {
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  div = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
  a = div.getElementsByTagName("a");

  for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (a[i].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      a[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      a[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
function filterFunction() {
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput2");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  div = document.getElementById("myDropdown2");
  a = div.getElementsByTagName("a");

  for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (a[i].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      a[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      a[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
body{height:600px;}
#myInput {
  border-box: box-sizing;
  background-image: url('../Website/Img/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 14px 12px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 14px 20px 12px 45px;
  border: none;
  width: 100%;
}

.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 10%;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 2;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #eee}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button onMouseOver="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Drop-down</button>
      <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." id="myInput" onkeyup="filterFunction()">
        <a href="#">Link_1 </a>
        <a href="#">Link_2 </a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="dropdown">
      <button onMouseOver="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Drop-down 2</button>
      <div id="myDropdown2" class="dropdown-content">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." id="myInput2" onkeyup="filterFunction()">
        <a href="#">Link_3 </a>
        <a href="#">Link_4 </a>
      </div>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This doesn't work.  You are being redundant in the names you give your functions.  The second declaration of each function overwrites the first.  Try filtering the first dropdown, and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: I'll try Thanks you!

Answer (score 0):

No two elements in the DOM can have the same ID.  You've give both `id="myDropdown"`, so your code is finding the first element with this ID, and stopping there.

Instead, try using the `event` argument of your event listeners.  It's got all sorts of goodies to tell you which DOM element spurred the handler.  Check this out:

```js
function myFunction(event) { 
    event.target.classList.toggle("show");
}

function filterFunction(event) {
    var input, filter, div, a, i;
    input = event.target;
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    div = input.parentElement;
    a = div.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (a[i].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            a[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            a[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

```css
#myInput {
    border-box: box-sizing;
    background-image: url('../Website/Img/searchicon.png');
    background-position: 14px 12px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 14px 20px 12px 45px;
    border: none;
    width: 100%;
}

.dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 10%;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 2;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    font-size: 18px;
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #eee}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
   display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}
```

```html
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button onMouseOver="myFunction(event)" class="dropbtn">Drop-down</button>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." onkeyup="filterFunction(event)">
                <a href="#">Link_1 </a>
                <a href="#">Link_2 </a>
          </div>
          </div>

        <div class="dropdown">
            <button onMouseOver="myFunction(event)" class="dropbtn">Drop-down 2</button>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." onkeyup="filterFunction(event)">
                <a href="#">Link_3 </a>
                <a href="#">Link_4 </a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Note that it's necessary to pass the event in, where you're attaching the functions in the DOM:

`<input type="text" placeholder="Search.." id="myInput" onkeyup="filterFunction(event)">`